# При входе на localhost/phpmyadmin выдает http error 500. Что делать?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, логирование

Сервер на ubuntu server 17.10

Вот логи apache2 : https://pastebin.com/C8efPPL5

Comment: похоже плохо встал php - он не находит библиотеки. странно это

Comment: для начала создайте простой файл index,php с phpinfo() и проверьте есть ли он вообще, после можноо будет понять более точно

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка связана с отсутствием ряда необходимых файлов (либо ошибка их открытия).Возможно отсутствует файл или каталог. восстановите файлы и программа запустится.